# jsonParser objectWithString returns null value

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

declared in .h file

```
 NSString *extractUsersGRC;
```

.m file

```
{
  ..
     extractUsersGRC=[[NSString alloc]init]; 
     extractUsersGRC = [[resultsGRC objectForKey:@"d"] retain];

     NSDictionary *dict1 =[[NSDictionary alloc]init];

     dict1=[[extractUsersGRC  JSONValue]retain];
 }
```

[image]

---

- I am using json to get data from web service and web service is ok
  replaying my request, but some times I am getting **dict1** as nil.
  jsonvalue returns me null.So where i am making mistake.
- extractUsersGRC holding data but Jsonvalue returns null..? why ? I am
  not getting Help me.

[image]

```
SBJSON  *jsonGRC = [SBJSON new];
    jsonGRC.humanReadable = YES;
    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

    NSString *service = @"/GET_Recent_Activity";


    NSString *flagval=@"C";

    double latval=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"LATITUDE"]doubleValue];
    double longval=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"LONGITUDE"]doubleValue];
    NSString *userid=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"UserID"];
    long u_id= [userid longLongValue];
    NSLog(@"%ld",u_id);

    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"flag\":\"%@\",\"current_Lat\":\"%f\",\"current_Long\":\"%f\",\"userid\":\"%ld\"}",flagval,latval,longval,u_id];

    NSLog(@"request string:%@",requestString);


    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [requestString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];

    NSString *fileLoc = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"URLName" ofType:@"plist"];
    fileContentsGRC = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileLoc];

    urlLocGRC = [fileContentsGRC objectForKey:@"URL"];

    urlLocGRC = [urlLocGRC stringByAppendingString:service];
    NSLog(@"URL : %@",urlLocGRC);

    requestGRC = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlLocGRC]];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]];
    [requestGRC setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [requestGRC setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [requestGRC setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [requestGRC setHTTPBody: requestData];


    NSError *respError = nil;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: requestGRC returningResponse: nil error: &respError ];
```

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil]; this line will give you json data without json class

Comment: Try with NSMutableDictionary... :) and make sure `extractUsersGRC` has data ??

Comment: @iPatel yes,extracUSerGRC has always data.

Comment: @ChitraKhatri thanks, but your code also returning null, i am not sure but do i have to use valueforkey:@"Checkin" in your code.

Comment: Just put code of your send request.. are you using `NSMutableData` for get response from server ??

Comment: @utka , Did you create category for this jsonValue method??

Comment: @iPatel I have placed code for my request

Comment: @HussainShabbir I dont have any idea about category, if you have any reference then please provide me.

Comment: This is the category referencehttp://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html. But my question is what is this jsonValue here?? I believe it is not objective-c method.

Comment: is your url correct? check it first

Comment: @utkalpatel - see my answer and replay me, is it helpful for you or not ?? and make sure that your response is not ZIP file ??

Answer (score 0):

Declare `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *returnData;` at `.h` file and 
follow me

change your `NSURLConnection` declaration

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (theConnection)
  self.returnData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
else
  NSLog(@"Connection Failed!");
```

and delegate method of `NSURLConnection`

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [self.returnData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.returnData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"Connection failed." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableDictionary *jsonDictionary  = [jsonString JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonDictionary);
}
```